# Local Parse Server throwing 'unauthorised' despite correct keys

Tags: parse-platform, http-status-code-403, unauthorized, parse-server

I'm setting up a local Parse Server: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server

I'm setting my keys as per the link above yet still getting 'Unauthorised'. Any ideas why this is?

Here's the snippet where I create the server var:

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;

var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

// Specify the connection string for your mongodb database
// and the location to your Parse cloud code
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: 'mongodb://localhost:27017',
  cloud: '/Users/jack/Desktop/dev/node_modules/parse-server/lib/cloud/main.js', // Provide an absolute path
  appId: 'jack1234',
  masterKey: 'jack1234',
  serverURL: 'http://localhost:' + port + '/parse'
});

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
app.use('/parse', api);

// Hello world
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('Express is running here.');
});

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});
```

Here's a screenshot of the Unauthorised:

[image: unauthorised]

Answer (score 1):

You need to wirte the value in the header without '' (Apostrophe).

like:

```
X-Parse-Application-Id : jack1234
```

Comment: Ended up starting from scratch and using the Parse-Server-Example repo on GitHub which solved the issue. Plus, had to drop the ""s too cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be from the headers you are sending to the ending. this is why you get the 403 code. I'm guessing the server does not recognize requests with these headers.

```
// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
app.use('/parse', api);
```

On this line shown above you are injecting the arguments in which the express app needs to be authenticated with. So why not just make a request to it without the Headers ?